# Simulating an AJAX-ified form submit on keyDown?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have a remote form consisting of a text area and a submit button. If I type text and hit submit, a model is successfully created and the `format.js` is invoked correctly, causing the text to fade in above.

However, I want to be able to submit the form by pressing enter. Since it's a text-area, that's not possible unless I add a `keyUp`. However, after doing this I noticed some strange behavior. I tried calling the `$('#my_form').submit()` as well as `$('#my_form > input').click()`.

The model is created successfully (as witnessed if I reload the page, I can see it listed about with the rest), but for some strange reason, my controller is not actually calling `format.js`. Keep in mind that everything works fine if I **actually** click the submit button, but not if I invoke it with a keyDown on the textarea.

If anyone knows why this is happening, and can possibly suggest a solution, I would be very grateful as it's been bugging me for quite some time.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to do this:

```
$('.some-div-here textarea').live('keydown', function(event) {
  if(event.keyCode == '13') {
    $('#my_form').submit();

    return false;
  }
});
```

In the eyes of the Rails controller, there should be no difference between manually clicking the submit button and having jQuery submit it for you.

If you look in the Rails logs, you should be able to see:

> Started POST "/some/route" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-12-04 21:23:51 -0500
>
> Processing by YourController#your_action as JS

If it says `as JS` then it should render `format.js` by default.

Comment: See, it's definitely submitting - because if I manually reload the page, I can see the text listed. The only problem is, the actually javascript code (for me it's create.js.erb) is never executing when invoked by format.js. It works when I click the submit button, but not when I manually call $('#my_form').submit().

Comment: So you're saying it's rendering the code but the JS code is not running?  You might want to wrap it in a javascript tag

Comment: It's strange indeed. I have some code in create.js.erb that basically alerts (just so I can see if it runs), then adds a new list element with the @item that was just created. If I click the submit button. The create method is invoked, create.js.erb is rendered, an alert comes up, and the text is placed accordingly. However, if I call $('#my_form').submit() on keydown in the text area, the form submits (meaning it invokes the create method and makes a new record in the database), but create.js.erb is never rendered and therefore never executes.

Comment: Do both events show up in the logs as being processed `as JS`?  You may try explicitly calling `render :partial => "somecontroller/create.js"` in the controller instead of responding with `format.js`

Comment: Yeah, make sure you're using `keydown` and not `keyup` like in my sample code above.  Key up still sends a newline character whereas key down should not.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. The issue was occurring because it was attempting to send the text with \r\n at the end of it. If I hit enter (and no matter what keys after I pressed), the Submit button it self did not even work. To fix this, I simply cut off the trailing \r\n before submitting.